# R:: Dplyr: How to get each Monday in a specific date range + count it

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data on when an ATP Tennis tournament took place with two columns in the following format:

| Tournament | Date Range |
| --- | --- |
| Australian Open | 20.01.2020 - 02.02.2020 |

Now the goal is to predict the participation but solely for each Monday, if the date range contains a Monday of course! Also since once you lose you are out in Tennis, I am assuming that the participation in the second week is higher since then only the good players are left in the tournament. Which is why we would need to know if it is week one or two in the tournament.
Hence for the above example we would need something like this at the end:

| Tournament | Date | Number of week

|Australian Open      |20.01.2022| 1 |

|Australien Open      |27.01.2022| 2 |

I know that I can count in dplyr but how would you get "only Monday" that is compatible with Dplyr? Essentially in SQL "where DAYOFWEEK(Column) = 2)".

I guess first one would need to separate the date range into two columns?
Search function didn't yield nothing covering such a specific problem, hence it could help someone in future.
Cheers vie2bgd
#############################################
#############################################

Edit:
after working day and night I almost have it but am missing on the last step ... also sorry but it's my first post, no need to ghost me or give me immediate minus points thanks @NirGraham at least giving me some hints, much appreciated and will try to implement it but technically I shared data up there in line with an instruction here how to do it, simply separating by | simply forgot some point "... "...
here is what I did so far:

```
#first I separated the initial range into 2 columns
tennis.orf.2020.2 = tennis.orf.2020 %>% separate(Datum, c("Start", "End"), sep = " - ")

x=tennis.orf.2020.2 %>%
  mutate(across(c(Start, End), as.Date, "%d.%m.%y")) %>% 
  transmute(Tournament, date = map2(Start, End, seq, by = 'day')) %>% 
  unnest(c(date)) %>% 
  filter(wday(date) == 2) %>%
  count(Tournament,date)
```

| Tournament | Date | Number of week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Australian Open | 2020-01-20 | 1 |
| Australian Open | 2020-01-27 | 1 |

This should be the result:

| Tournament | Date | Number of week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Australian Open | 2020-01-20 | 1 |
| Australian Open | 2020-01-27 | 2 |

If I group by tournament I lose a row :(
################################################

EDIT2:
Nevermind got it finally although it makes zero sense,

hopefully this will help somebody out there and save at least somebody valuable time

```
x%>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(Tournament) %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  mutate(times = cumsum(dummy)) %>%
  select(-dummy)
```

Comment: you could take further steps to make it more convenient for other forum users to help you.

Share some representative data that will enable your code to run and show the problematic behaviour.

You might use tools such as the library datapasta, or the base function dput() to share a portion of data in code form, i.e. that can be copied from forum and pasted to R session.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-how-to-do-a-minimal-reproducible-example-reprex-for-beginners/23061

Comment: your code is written to compute on some object called `tennis.orf.2020` that we don't have; use the methods linked to in the tutorial I provided to share a sample of `tennis.orf.2020`; probably the first 10 entries would be enough; OR if you are happy with `tennis.orf.2020.2` and will use that as your start, then a sample of *that*

Comment: the first table i posted is: tennis.orf.2020 @NirGraham 

| Tournament | Date Range |
| --- | --- |
|Australian Open |20.01.2020 - 02.02.2020|

Comment: @vie2bgd The nicest way to share data is using `dput()`--this is creates a copy/pasteable version of an R object, including all class and structure information. For example you can use `dput(x[1:3, ])` to make a copy/pasteable version of the first 3 rows of `x`. It's a little easier on answerers than copy/pasting tables and having to read them into R and guessing about column classes and such. That said, @Nir, in a case like this where there aren't spaces within fields and it seems like default classes for everything, using `read.table(text = {{copied table}}, header = T)` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` helper function for this:

```
x%>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(Tournament) %>%
  mutate(times = row_number())
```

This is a more concise equivalent of your code with the `cumsum(dummy)`.